# Office Online Server is taking long time to perform the auto-save operation

Tags: ms-wopi, office-online-server

We integrated Office Online Server in our web application and in the WOPI web integration we are setting File URL properties such as `FileUrl`. This URL points to `/wopi/files/{file_id}/contents` link and internally, it will call the API once we start editing the document.

From this API, we are updating the file version but the issue is that after editing the WOPI document, the triggering of the API `/wopi/files/{file_id}/contents` is taking a long time and we are unable to find how it is getting triggered? Is there a way we can trigger this method directly?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Please check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for how to clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

So if I get it right it takes a long time BEFORE the `/wopi/files/{file_id}/contents` endpoint is hit.
In such a case, I'd recommend four things:

1. Run the WOPI host in a debug mode and trigger the endpoint from the OOS machine manually and see if there are any delays related to the network infrastructure.
2. Checking whether you set the [WOPI host capabilities](https://wopi.readthedocs.io/projects/wopirest/en/latest/files/CheckFileInfo.html#wopi-host-capabilities-properties) right in the `CheckFileInfo`. If you set the WOPI Client's expectations incorrectly, it may take time for it to figure out what's going on and potentially fall back to a different method.
3. Using the [WOPI validator app](https://wopi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_test_ship/validator.html#validator)
4. Checking the event viewer for any errors related to a specific [Session ID](https://wopi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_test_ship/troubleshooting.html#session-ids) and [Correlation ID](https://wopi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_test_ship/troubleshooting.html#correlation-ids)

[image: Windows Event Viewer -> Application and Service Logs -> Microsoft Office Web Apps]

Comment: HI @rocky thank you for the reply and i have 1 more question about auto save frequency call which office online server makes for example for excel file the auto save frequency call is made 2 minutes after editing session is done and for ppt it takes 3 minutes after editing session is completed.is there a way we can reduce this time it takes to call this auto save frequency ?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to influence the autosave intervals. And I think it's not even desirable. From my experience, the interval is variable, not static. The WOPI client (OOS) has its own algorithm determining the optimal time for the autosave (based on the number of changes, last sync, and other factors). You don't have to worry that you lose data because even if you close the page/frame, WOPI client sends the unsaved changes to the WOPI host.