# Issues on loading files with WOPI integration

Tags: ms-wopi

[UPDATE]Even if I still have issues, the problem here was that BaseFileName needs a filename with also the extension.

I've done a WOPI integration but I have issues in loading the office document.

My host is registered to the Cloud Storage Partner Program.

I see from the logs that the frontend performs the first checkInfo call to the backend but then it doesn't happen anything and it keeps showing the word icon.

The backend url is https://{host}/wopi/files/{fileId}

and my form content is

```
<form id="office_form" name="office_form" target="office_frame"
  action="https://FFC-word-view.officeapps.live.com/wv/wordviewerframe.aspx?WOPISrc=https://{host_url}/wopi/files/1234567&access_token=DASDASAS" method="post">
    <input name="access_token" value="1" type="hidden" />
    <input name="access_token_ttl" value="1000" type="hidden" />
    <input name="user_id" value="1" type="hidden" />
    <input name="owner_id" value="1" type="hidden" />
</form>
```

The answer to my checkFileInfo is:

200OK

> {"BaseFileName":"123456","OwnerId":"Microsoft Office
> User;","Size":6116,"UserId":"Francesca","Version":"1","UserFriendlyName":"Hello","SupportsUpdate":true,"SupportsLocks":true,"SupportsGetLock":true,"SupportsExtendedLockLength":true,"UserCanWrite":true,"SupportsUserInfo":true,"UserInfo":"PutUserInfoTest"}

Do you have any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: 1) Does the CheckFileInfo response end up with 200 and does it contain the correct payload (can you post it here)?
2) Try disabling all authNZ and put a breakpoint in your GetFile method - does it get hit? If not, it's very likely there's something wrong with your CheckFileInfo response.

Comment: Hi rocky, I've updated my message adding the response to the checkfileinfo. I made small progresses, now I see the word header but nothing more.

Comment: the checkfileinfo looks ok from the first glance. does the getfile method get hit?

Comment: No, it doesn't. The frontend changes from a page with the word icon looping to another blank one with only a blue header with the word icon

Comment: Can you try step #4 from my answer here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/62384305/1332034

Comment: I've fixed the issue: nothing related to communication problems, only access_token_ttl had an invalid value. For test purposes I put it as 0, which I read means no expiration